# Why does my RigidBody Z direction not move? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm using this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            Debug.Log("pressed");
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 5);

        }
    }
}
```

Fairly simple, when I pres space the player jumps. When I press the up key, I get a log in the console but the player doesnt move at all. I'm stumped, been debugging for a while now.

Anybody that knows why?

Following this tutorial by the way: https://youtu.be/54qz4SyQWZM?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuB5ATsJZLKX3AW4V9XaIV9b&t=2265

Edit: Here are my object settings https://gyazo.com/3ec3a192b401f6335547beb84e07d8fb

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with friction? Try adding physics material to your collider and reduce its friction to 0.

Comment: Thanks, tried it but didnt work unfortunately! Also: I tried a normale cube with the same script, it only jumps, also doesnt move forward

Comment: I fixed it! Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Had to disable "Apply Root Motion" on my player object animator.

https://gyazo.com/401c5f12b5bb4cf5aab1f0d94990353b